# Windows hard link taking up space?

Tags: windows-7, windows, symbolic-link, hardlink, mklink

On my computer I create a hard link

```
mklink /h git-link.exe git.exe
Hardlink created for git-link.exe <<===>> git.exe
```

Now they both take up space

```
2012-04-17  12:14 AM         6,905,039 git-link.exe
2012-04-17  12:14 AM         6,905,039 git.exe
```

What's the point of this? Why not just make a copy?

Comment: The number you see, "6,905,039" has nothing to do with how many bytes of space anything takes up. It's the size of the linked file if you were to read it, regardless of how many bytes it actually takes up on disk. So all that your output shows is that each of the two links point to a file that would read as that number of bytes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you create a hardlink, you are creating two separate file system entries pointing to the same physical data on the disk.

When you do a dir, it displays the size of the data being stored at the location the file system entry is pointing at.

So if you create 100 hard links to a single file, they will all report the same size - they are reporting the size of the data stored.  This does not mean that the hardlinks take up this space - in fact they do not.  A hard link takes up very little space.

Comment: Also, when you create a file in a directory, it's a hard link that puts the file in that directory. The `mklink /h` creates an *additional* link to the file that behaves precisely the same as the original link. (If you remove the original link by deleting the directory entry, the file will be just as if you had originally created it in the other directory.)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/disk-space-problems-on-ntfs-volumes#other-ntfs-features-that-may-cause-file-allocation-confusion) provided by Microsoft may be helpful. (Although it's for Windows Server 2003, I think it should be the same for all systems using NTFS file system.)

For hard links:

> Windows Explorer and a command prompt show all linked files as being the same size, even though they all share the same data and **do not actually use that amount of disk space**.

> Windows Explorer and a dir /s command follow the reparse point, count any files and folders on the destination volume, and then include them in the host volume's statistics. This may mislead you to believe that more space is being used on the host volume than what is actually being used.

> You can use chkdsk output, NTBackup GUI or backup logs, and the viewing of disk quotas to determine how disk space is being used on a volume. However, Windows Explorer and the dir command have some limitations and drawbacks when used for this purpose.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -3):

Fact is, there is no point in ever using directory hard links (junctions), is there ?

Considering the way they are handled by explorer, that is.

My point, using an example : one cannot hope to alleviate  disk 'C' from its physical payload (moving appdata folders or program files to another disk 'E' and using hardlinks to repopulate 'C', thus keeping apps working). Windows explorer will still accumulate those links "sizes" to the -presumably- consumed space on 'C', throwing warnings at its user's face as soon as disk 'C' lacks free space, even if it relates to hardlinks "virtual" space consumption.

So, Windows 7's hard links ? Big disappointment.

Comment: You confuse hard links with symbolic links.